# PHP display group by with two criteria

Tags: mysql

I would like to display MySQL database group by month and year basis two field value.

From table:

```
aDate
2013-12-02
2013-12-04
2013-11-03
2013-11-06
2012-01-02
2012-01-05
```

To:

```
2013-12
2013-11
2012-01
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Sorry, it is only one column.

Comment: Then your question has already been answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select date_format( datefield, '%Y-%m' )
  from table
 group by date_format( datefield, '%Y-%m' )
```

If you need in that specific order, put at end

```
order by 1 desc
```

`1` means the first selected element. On this case `date_format( datefield, '%Y-%m' )`

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad61b/2